# jQuery ui autocomplete for custom data rendering issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Actually I tried for jquery autocomplete for category of items.I have a code block like this and trying to get the `id` of the selected item that is the attribute of appended guaranter span. So how can i get the `id` when I select one category from the list.

***JS CODE***

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var that = this;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            var li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            li.append('\
                <span style="font-size:10px; padding:2px;" class="guaranter" id="' + item.id + '">Guaranter:' + item.guaranter + '</span><br>\
                <span style="font-size:10px; padding:2px;">Father\'s Name:' + item.father_name + '</span><br>\
                <span style="font-size:10px; padding:2px;">District:' + item.district + '</span><br>\
                <span style="font-size:10px; padding:2px;"> National ID:' + item.national_info + '</span><br>\
                <span style="font-size:10px; padding:2px;">Contact:' + item.contact_number_personal + '</span>');
        });
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

on select of your li use like this.

```
$(this).find('.guaranter').attr('id'); //here this is current selected li, you need to handle the event in select method.
```